# swat installation on server 16

Tags: samba

Im not able to install SWAT on Ubuntu server 16.10. It's showing

> error:E:Unable to locate package samba-swat

and I don't know how to set user level security permissions in samba.

Comment: I think that the package name is just swat.

Comment: i tried but its still showing the same error